# FileNotFoundException on Gradle 2.8 cache.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, filenotfoundexception

When I was about to build I got:

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GIT\sampleproject\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
> C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GIT\sampleproject\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have followed every related solution to this same error from others like:

```
- deleting contents of `%TEMP%
- deleting all the cache.lock.properties inside .gradle\caches\2.8\scripts
- changing the "Service directoy path" of gradle to a custom location in "C:/Gradle/.gradle"
  (I placed it in the root location instead of in a specific user folder. I have multiple user accounts in my Windows, I'm not sure if this has something to do with it.)
```

But all of these to no avail. I even uninstalled an **INSTALLED Android Studio** (using the executable installer) and changed it to a **PACKAGED Android Studio**, still it didn't fix it.

I feel like I'm already going circled. Has anyone found a concrete solution to this? Or could I just use someone's working Android Studio and copy their `cache.properties` and paste it in mine?

Comment: open your project, even you would see an error and in gradle-wrapper.properties chcnge gradle version like 2.5. It should rebuild and download it again.

Comment: @piotrek1543 where is this `gradle-wrapper.properties` located? and are you suggesting i should downgrade my gradle?

Comment: Open your Android Studio press four times SHIFT then in shon console write file name and enter. It is in your app folder. Yes, try first to downgrade, if it would work, than you would upgrade. As you see gradle missing some files so you need to recreate it. Try to do it by downgrade